# Possible bug in zooming in on Vaadin charts when more than 1 series present?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

Earlier, I asked how to create "spectra" charts in Vaadin (see [How to create a "spectrum" chart using Vaadin 14+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760759/how-to-create-a-spectrum-chart-using-vaadin-14)). It turned out that one didn't actually need to create barcharts -- the only real need seemed to be to set the pointwidth to 1. (This solved the "very wide" widths lines when zooming.)

HOWEVER: I think there's a bug in vaadin charts when one has more than 1 series presents and when one zooms: the line *moves* to an inccorrect position on the x-axis (or the x-axis is no longer placed correctly.) Any thoughts on how to resolve? Here are two screenshots showing the problem. In the first one, only ONE series is visible and the line is at the *correct* x-axis point of ~598.36. In the second screenshot, though, (where the *only* change I have made is to enable the 2nd series), the line moves to an INCORRECT x-axis coordinate (it seems like it's ~598.25!!!).

[image]

[image]

One theory I have is that adding the second series somehow confuses the chart from determining the correct x-axes....maybe because each series has it's own x axis logic in some way? Not sure....(I'm using Vaadin 14 and I tested this both in my dev env and on production.)

Comment: (Minor FYI: I take back what I said about "not needing to create barcharts". You still need to create column charts.)

Comment: That doesn't seem to happen in the zoomed example I posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62818130/4502058
Could you include a simple code snippet and the required steps to reproduce this behavior? If you think it's an issue feel free to report it in http://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/issues/new with corresponding reproduction example and steps.